# What kind of css selector is this ? What does it mean?

Tags: css, css-selectors

While trying to understand bootstrap I came across this :

`.control-group.error input, [...] {
   [...]
}`

It looks like a descendant selector but .control-group.error is a class.

I looked through this and I couldn't find anything : http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/

Can anyone give me some pointers ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, `.control-group.error` will match any elements that have both `control-group` and `error` class names.

As you said, the `input` will match any `input` element that is a descendant of any element with the class names `control-group` and `error`.

For example, it would match:

```html
<form class="control-group error">
    <input> <!-- It matches this (both class names on form) -->
</form>
```

And it would not match:

```html
<form class="control-group">
    <input> <!-- It won't match this (only one of the class names on form) -->
</form>
```

Comment: I understand the first part of your answer http://jsfiddle.net/cantcopy/hAVsh/ but not the second http://jsfiddle.net/cantcopy/hAVsh/1/

Comment: @Mickey06 - In your 2nd fiddle the inner `span` inherits the styles from the outer `span`.